# A device to make a bridge

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, bridge, wireless-bridge

I want to buy a device to use as a bridge, let me explain what I need exactly.
I need to use VPN on my connection, I have internet via a Cisco Router which I don't have access to the panel, so I want to buy a device to set the VPN connection on it then this device can connect to WiFi and then my other devices connect to this device!

I want to know is there any device to do this? and what's the name of this device?

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to buy anything: a PC can be used as a WiFi hotspot, sharing its connection. This ability is built into [Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027762/windows-use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot) OS and Linux, such as [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html.en).

Some VPN providers, such as [ExpressVPN](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/vpn-setup/share-vpn-connection-windows/), provide directions, as well.

You'd achieve best speed using an Ethernet connection to the PC.